# Data passing between the ASP.NET MVC 3 view hierarchy

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

### Motivation

I want to be able to build up a tree-like object hierarchy in Javascript that corresponds to the ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor views on a page. The plan is to have a one-to-one correspondence between a Razor view and a Javascript file where its logic is defined (in form of a constructor function that will accept some initialization parameters). Simple example could look like this :

- `_Layout.cshtml <-> Global.js`

  - `SplitterPane.cshtml <-> SplitterPane.js`

    - `Grid.cshtml <-> Grid.js`
    - `Tree.cshtml <-> Tree.js`

I would use the constructors to build a hierarchy, e.g.

```
var page = new Global(global_options);
var splitter = new SplitterPane(splitter_options);
var grid = new Grid(grid_options);
var tree = new Tree(tree_options);

page.addChild(splitter);
splitter.addChild(grid);
splitter.addChild(tree);
```

All of this code should be of course constructed automatically in the context of the root (layout) view from metadata collected from the partial views. Metadata provided by a view contains the options necessary to initialize its Javascript object and the Javascript files to load.

### Problem

Unlike WebForms, MVC views do not have any natural hierarchy I would know of and passing information between a view and its partial (sub)views seems rather tricky. In case of using helpers like `Html.Action` in the view the whole processing of a "subview" happens independently, so they don't even share the `Page` object. What I need is some kind of a central place where the views can deposit their metadata as they are rendered so that it can be used in the layout view to combine and output the complete script.

### Solution ?

One way I could think of was to use the `HttpContext.Current.Items` to temporarily store a collection of view metadata objects. All the views would deposit the metadata there and layout view would use it. The order of execution seems to match my expectation, however I'm still unable to reconstruct the tree hierarchy of views. To be able to do that, I would need to use a stack where a view would register on start of its rendering and unregister on the end, so that the parent can be found on the top.

1. Is there a way to have some pre-/post-render hooks where I could put this logic ?
2. Is this even a good idea in the first place ?
3. Is there a completely different solution that I don't see ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom view engine:

```
public class MyViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    private class MyRazorView : RazorView
    {
        public MyRazorView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string layoutPath, bool runViewStartPages, IEnumerable<string> viewStartFileExtensions, IViewPageActivator viewPageActivator)
            : base(controllerContext, viewPath, layoutPath, runViewStartPages, viewStartFileExtensions)
        {
        }

        protected override void RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, System.IO.TextWriter writer, object instance)
        {
            var stack = viewContext.HttpContext.Items["stack"] as Stack<string>;
            if (stack == null)
            {
                stack = new Stack<string>();
                viewContext.HttpContext.Items["stack"] = stack;
            }
            // depending on the required logic you could
            // use a stack of some model and push some additional
            // information about the view (see below)
            stack.Push(this.ViewPath);
            base.RenderView(viewContext, writer, instance);
        }
    }

    protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
    {
        return new MyRazorView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath, true, base.FileExtensions, base.ViewPageActivator);
    }

    protected override IView CreatePartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
    {
        return new MyRazorView(controllerContext, partialPath, null, false, base.FileExtensions, base.ViewPageActivator);
    }
}
```

that you would register in `Application_Start`:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyViewEngine());
```

and now you can write a custom HTML helper that will pick the stack that was stored in the HttpContext and do something useful:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString BuildTree(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        var stack = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["stack"] as Stack<string>;
        if (stack == null)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }


        // TODO: your custom logic to build the tree
        ...
    }
}
```

and in the end of your _Layout:

```
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        @Html.BuildTree()
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What a nice and thorough solution !!

Comment: Thanks, that sounds cool.. the only thing that's missing to reconstruct the tree is the link between the parent and child view. I guess I could do that by keeping a parallel "parent" stack where I would push an item before a call of base.RenderView and pop it after the call. That should work, right ?

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to associate a view with a Javascript file, define a section in your layout.cshtml (before the close of the body tag):

```
@RenderSection("scripts", false")
```

Then in your pages and views:

```
@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript" src="path to script"></script> }
```

However, this will not work once you get down to partial views.  To handle partial views, I've used a custom Html extension.  @Html.RenderResource("{sectionname}, "~/{path to resource}")

Comment: As you said, sections don't work on partial views. The extension you mention uses a similar method like my proposed solution so all the three questions I asked still apply :)